# Lisp exit defun function with nil as value

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to do a recursive version of the function position called `positionRec`. The objective is define the position of an element in a list, and if the element is not in the list return "nil". For exemple:
(positionRec 'a '(b c d a e)) => 4
(positionRec 'a '(b c d e)) => nil

I have written:

```
(defun positionRec (c l)
  (cond
   ((atom l) (return nil))
   ((equal c (first l)) 1)
   (t (+ 1 (positionRec c (rest l)))) ) )
```

I don't succeed to return nil. I have an error *"*** - return-from: no block named nil is currently visible"*

Anyone can teach me how to do it?

Comment: Sometimes is easier than you think in the first place  Just skip the `return` and go with a single `nil` should do the trick.

Comment: You might want to make this tail recursive (some lisps have tail call optimization and it would be a waste not to give them the chance to work their magic): `(defun osition-rec (c l) (labels ((iter (i lst) (if lst (if (equal c (first lst))  i  (iter (+ i 1) (rest lst))) nil))) (iter 1 l)))`

Answer (score 3):

Lisp is an *expression language*: it has only expressions an no statemends.  This means that the value of a call to a function is simply the value of the last form involved in that call  This is different than many languages which have both statements and expressions and where you have to explicitly litter your code with explicit `return`s to say what the value of a function call is.

A `cond` form in turn is an expression.  The value of an expression like

```
(cond
 (<test1> <test1-form1> ... <test1-formn>)
 (<test2> <test1-form1> ... <test1-formn>)
 ...
 (<testn> <testn-form1> ... <testn-formnn>))
```

is the `<testm-formn>` of the first `<testm>` which is true, or `nil` if none of them are (and as a special case, if there are no forms after a test which is true the value is the value of that test).

So in your code you just need to make sure that the last form in the test which succeeds is the value you want:

```
(defun positionRec (c l)
  (cond
   ((atom l) nil)
   ((equal c (first l)) 1)
   (t (+ 1 (positionRec c (rest l))))))
```

So, what use is `return`?  Well, sometimes you really do want to say 'OK, in the middle of some complicated loop or something, and I'm done now':

```
(defun complicated-search (...)
  (dolist (...)
    (dolist (...)
      (dotimes (...)
        (when <found-the-interesting-thing>
          (return-from complicated-search ...))))))
```

`return` itself is simply equivalent to `(return-from nil ...)` and various constructs wrap `block`s named `nil` around their bodies.  Two such, in fact, are `dotimes` and `dolist`, so if you want to escape from a big loop early you can do that:

```
(defun complicated-search (...)
  (dolist (...)
    (when ...
      (return 3))))                     ;same as (return-from nil 3)
```

But in general because Lisp is an expression language you need to use `return` / `return-from` much less often than you do in some other languages.

In your case, the modified function is going to fail: if you get to the `((atom l) nil)` case, then it will return `nil` to its parent which will ... try to add `1` to that.  A better approach is to keep count of where you are:

```
(defun position-of (c l)
  (position-of-loop c l 1))

(defun position-of-loop (c l p)
  (cond
   ((atom l) nil)
   ((equal c (first l)) p)
   (t (position-of-loop c (rest l) (1+ p)))))
```

Note that this (as your original) uses 1-based indexing: zero-based would be more compatible with the rest of CL.

It would probably be idiomatic to make `position-of-loop` a local function:

```
(defun position-of (c l)
  (labels ((position-of-loop (lt p)
             (cond
              ((atom lt) nil)
              ((equal c (first lt)) p)
              (t (position-of-loop (rest lt) (1+ p))))))
    (position-of-loop l 1)))
```

And you could then use an [iteration macro](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#applicative-iteration-iterate) if you wanted to make it a bit more concise:

```
(defun position-of (c l)
  (iterate position-of-loop ((lt l) (p 1))
    (cond
     ((atom lt) nil)
     ((equal c (first lt)) p)
     (t (position-of-loop (rest lt) (1+ p))))))
```

Comment: ohh. Understood for the indexing, I will change it. And thank for the example of the local function and the iteration macro. I've learned new things.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're trying to deal with incommensurable values. On the one hand, you want to deak with numbers, on the other, you want to deal with the empty list. You cannot add a number to a list, but you will inherently try doing so (you have an unconditional `(1+ ...)` call in your default branch in your `cond`).

There are ways to work around that, one being to capture the value:

```
(cond
  ...
  (t (let ((val (positionRec c (rest l))))
        (when val ;; Here we "pun" on nil being both false and the "not found" value
           (1+ val)))))
```

Another would be to use a method amenable to tail-recursion:

```
(defun positionrec (element list &optional (pos 1))
  (cond ((null list) nil)
        ((eql element (head list)) pos)
        (t (positionrec element (rest list) (1+ pos)))))
```

The second function can (with a sufficently smart compiler) be turned into, basically, a loop. The way it works is by passing the return value as an optional parameter.

You could build a version using `return`, but you would probably need to make use of `labels` for that to be straight-forward (if you return `nil` directly from the function, it still ends up in the `(1+ ...)`, where you then have numerical incompatibility) so I would go with either "explicitly capture the value and do the comparison against nil/false" or "the version amenable to tail-call elimination" and simply pick the one you find the most readable.